# data.table between function handling NA values within fcase

Tags: r, data.table

Processing some messy data and wondering if `between()` can handle NA values in any way? Desired action would just be to return NA if there is an issue to be filtered out later.

```
library(data.table)
test <- data.frame(date=sample(1:9,1e7,replace = TRUE),
                   zip1=rep(1,1e7),
                   start1=c(rep(1,1e7-1),NA), 
                   end1=rep(3,1e7),
                   zip2=c(rep(2,1e7-1e2),rep(NA,1e2)),
                   start2=c(rep(4,1e7-1e2),rep(NA,1e2)),
                   end2=c(rep(6,1e7-1e2),rep(NA,1e2)),
                   zip3=c(rep(3,1e7-1e4),rep(NA,1e4)),
                   start3=c(rep(7,1e7-1e4),rep(NA,1e4)),
                   end3=c(rep(9,1e7-1e4),rep(NA,1e4)))
test$zip <- fcase(
  between(test$date, test$start1, test$end1),
  test$zip1,
  between(test$date, test$start2, test$end2),
  test$zip2,
  between(test$date, test$start3, test$end3),
  test$zip3
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact problem, but there is a `NAbounds=` argument to `between`, e.g.: `between(3, 1, NA, NAbounds=NA)` returns `NA` instead of a `TRUE`.

Comment: Ha, yeah. I couldn't get that to work which is why I posted. I just realized I also loaded tidyverse and that was really my issue. NAbounds+explicitly naming `data.table::between()` and I'm set. If you want internet points feel free to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is your desired.

```r
setDT(test)[,zip:=fcase(date %between% list(start1,end1),zip1,
                        date %between% list(start2,end2),zip2,
                        date %between% list(start3,end3),zip3)]
```